# Cipher used for request data encryption used by browser

Tags: ssl, encryption, browser, https

Using [Digicert's SSL mechanism explanation](https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm) I have understood how the data is encrypted between browser and server and below is my understanding.

1. Browser will send a request to server to get some resource. Server checks if the protocol of the request is HTTPS, if so then it will send its certificate (*this certificate is already signed by some CA (Certificate Authority, like Digicert)*) in the response.
2. Browser will check if the certificate is valid by validating if signing authority in its valid CA pool.
3. If browser founds that this certificate is signed by a valid CA then it generate a session key and encrypt it using the public key present in the certificate.
4. Browser will send this encrypted session key to the server and server will decrypt the session key, and will send back an acknowledgment to the browser which would be encrypted using the session key.
5. Above steps complete a **SSL handshake** and then secure communication starts between browser and server.

**Questions:**
Based on my above understanding, below are my questions for which I couldn't find the answer:

1. Browser will generate a session key and encrypt it using server's public key. But which encryption algorithm (or commonly called as Cipher) will be used the browser?
2. Once SSL handshake is completed, all communication will be encrypted using the symmetric session key, but again here as well which encryption algorithm (or commonly called as Cipher) will be used the browser?
3. Is the encryption algorithm used by browser any way depend upon certificate received from server?

   - Or for all encryption done by browser, same algorithm or cipher will be used.
4. Please correct me if I am wrong, algorithm or cipher information is also present in the certificate? How do that information is pushed into the certificate?

   - While generating the certificate do I need to tell which algorithm, how many bits encryption, padding etc.?

Based on above answer I will have the most important question - suppose I am providing my server private key to somebody so that he can monitor the SSL traffic for my server, then apart from providing him the private key what all other things I need to take care. And do I need to tell him the algorithm or cipher I am using at server?

Comment: Please don't ask 7 questions in a single post. Ask one (or two closely related) question(s) and go from there.

Comment: They are really logically related, I couldn't divide it. Also they may not make complete sense if divided and reading them together will help understand whole concept better. This is my personal opinion.

Comment: This question is better asked at security.stackexchange.com and I would recommend to read [How does SSL/TLS work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok, thanks for pointing to security.stackexchange.com, I will post it there. On a side note, my question is more about how cipher is picked up which is not answered in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Ciphersuite selection generally follows the below steps:

1. The client/ browser/ user agent suggests a list of supported cipher suites to the server during handshake. The list is ordered by client preference.
2. The server looks at its list of supported ciphers and chooses to use the cipher that is most preferred by the client.
3. If the server maintains cipher suite preferences (Apache: SSLHonorCipherOrder, nginx: ssl_prefer_server_ciphers, Lighttpd: ssl.honor-cipher-order, etc.), then it picks the first cipher from its list that is supported by the client (client preference is not honored).

** Certain servers and SSL implementations may have special conditions that restrict the use of a cipher suite with certain clients even if the client indicates support for a ciphersuite (to work around known bugs that are present in the client's SSL implementation). E.g., https://community.qualys.com/message/22681#22681

Comment: Thank you Anand for your inputs. I think yes it is correct that it driven by Cipher suite but then how does information at https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm holds true and in which context.